# Java applet connects to mysql in IDE but fails to connect in web browser

Tags: java, mysql, applet

I am trying hard to build an applet which takes input text from MYSQL database and displays on the screen. I get the connection to MySQL in when I run it netbeans but it fails when I run the same in browser with the error

> Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

Believe me I went through all the posts related to mine on this forum. But none of them was useful to me. I also tried **signing ** the JAR. But still it's not working.

Below is the code of the class which I want to execute from My JAR archive.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/MYdb";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "pass");
```

I went through all possible solutions on net. And finally I am posting over here.
Please help me in this.
If it's not possible the is there any other way to fetch data from database in an applet??
I am waiting for your valuable reply.
Thank you.

Comment: While it is certainly possible for an applet to connect to a DB, it is inherently unsafe.  An applet should be forced to access the DB via a servlet or similar that will mediate access.  Ask the DB/security experts why - 'SQL injection attacks' are the first thing that pops into my head, and I am not an expert on either DBs or security.

Answer (score 1):

When run from Netbeans, the applet runs from the `/test` directory or `/build` directory, from the application folder. Usually the drivers will be in `/lib` so no problem here.

When run from browser, the applet will be running from it's own jar file, so you will need to make that all the libraries (JDBC drivers) required are on your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply medopal.Yes. I added the libraries too.
Also when there are no drivers the error is "No suitable drivers found"
But here I am getting something different.
It proves it's getting the drivers but not getting access to mysql.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your new result; specific error text will be the most helpful.